# How to return sq-lite fetch data one function to another function for on load using angular in same controller

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

How do I return SQ-lite fetched data from one function to another function to use for on load using Angular in the same controller? Here is my code:

```
$scope.test = function(){       
    var datalength = '';
    db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DeviceModel', [], function (tx, res) {

            var len = res.rows.length;
            datalength = len;
            alert(datalength)
        })          
    });
    return datalength;
}
```

**Function Onload call:**

```
$scope.InsertMydevice = function() {
    $scope.test();
    alert(datalength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$q` Service to create a promise:

```
$scope.test = function(){       
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    db.transaction(function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DeviceModel', [], function (tx, res) {

            var datalength = res.rows.length;
            deferred.resolve(datalength);

        })          
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then extract the data from the promise:

```
$scope.InsertMydevice = function() {
    $scope.test().then(function(datalength) {
        console.log(datalength);
    });
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$q` into the controller.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)

Comment: That's why I said "Don't forget to inject $q into the controller". For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation).